# variables not working or not being detected

Tags: javascript, html

im working on a character randomizer and I'm having it randomize a list of fantasy races and then determine the maximum age based on the race. I've gotten it to show the race just fine but whenever it runs the age is inputted as "Average" and I have no idea why this is happening other than that when deciding the age limit "else" is set to say average. this code also is displayed on HTML and I don't think that is the problem but the javascript code and HTML code are both presented just in case.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <title>Character Randomizer 3.0</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Name</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <script src="IContraption.js"></script>
                <button class="button" onclick="getCharacters(), Character2();" style="font-family: sans-serif;">RUN</button>
                <input class="input" type="text" id="id1" name="id1" size="20" readonly />
                <input class="input" type="text" id="id2" name="id2" size="20" readonly />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
//Values
var Race;
var AgeType;

function getCharacters(){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    
    if (rnd === 1)
        Race = "DragonBorn";
    else if (rnd === 2)
        Race = "Dwarf";
    else if (rnd === 3)
        Race = "Elf";
    else if (rnd === 4)
        Race = "Gnome";
    else if (rnd === 5)
        Race = "Half-Elf";
    else if (rnd === 6)
        Race = "Halfling";
    else if (rnd === 7)
        Race = "Half-Orc";
    else if (rnd === 8)
        Race = "Tiefling";
    else
        Race = "Human";

    
}

function Character2(){
    
    if (Race === "DragonBorn")
        AgeType = "Average";
    else if (Race === "Dwarf")
        AgeType = "Dwarf";
    else if (Race === "Elf")
        AgeType = "Elf";
    else if (Race === "Gnome")
        AgeType = "Gnome";
    else if (Race === "Half-Elf")
        AgeType = "Half-Elf";
    else if (Race === "Half-Orc")
        AgeType = "Average";
    else if (Race === "Tiefling")
        AgeType = "Average";
    else if (Race === "Halfling")
        AgeType = "Halfling";
    else (Race === "Human")
        AgeType = "Average";
    
    document.getElementById('id2').value = AgeType;
    document.getElementById('id1').value = Race;
}
```

Comment: `else` followed by a condition is not valid syntax. The last few lines of `Character2()` do not work the way you think they do as a result.

Comment: You just missed an `if` there. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: `onclick="getCharacters(), Character2();" ` should to be `onclick="getCharacters(); Character2();"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed was the comma, but that ended up not being as important as I was assuming. Generally better practice is to use something like `onclick="getCharacters(); Character2();"` for performance reasons across browsers, if I remember correctly.

But the main thing was you needed to make sure that the last if statement was like so:

```js
    else if (Race === "Human")
        AgeType = "Average";
```

Whenever you have a statement like `(something === else)` then you need to make sure you always use if. `else` will default but errors out if you place an operator after it. It was essentially breaking after the `else` *then* assigning `Average` to `AgeType` because it was being compiled as outside of the above `else if` chain.

Your original code is processed as the following, and with brackets would look like this:

```js
    if (Race === "DragonBorn") {
        AgeType = "Average";
    } else if (Race === "Dwarf") {
        AgeType = "Dwarf";
    } else if (Race === "Elf") {
        AgeType = "Elf";
    } else if (Race === "Gnome") {
        AgeType = "Gnome";
    } else if (Race === "Half-Elf") {
        AgeType = "Half-Elf";
    } else if (Race === "Half-Orc") {
        AgeType = "Average";
    } else if (Race === "Tiefling") {
        AgeType = "Average";
    } else if (Race === "Halfling") {
        AgeType = "Halfling";
    } else {}
    (Race === "Human")
    AgeType = "Average";
```

Notice how it skips the `(Race === "Human)`.

I have saved a jsfiddle for you to play with here: https://jsfiddle.net/opensaurusrex/1o3k5Lam/1/